# Devise Forgot password is creating a link with localhost on product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

We're using the standard devise forgot password mailer:

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %></p>
```

On production this is generating a localhost url for Change Password:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=amqs2q9NcM1FerHKhmzV
```

This is strange given the production.rb file has our domain:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysite.com' }
```

Why is mysite.com not being used in the URL? Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My guess is that `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` is being overwritten somewhere. Do you have any file in `config/initializers` that affects `ActionMailer`?

Try running `rails console` on your production box and see what

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]
```

returns.

Comment: You are right it was being overwritten to `""` on Heroku

Comment: this helped! Thanks

Comment: Heroku uses the HOST ENV var itself I believe.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in **config/initializers/setup_mail.rb**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by simply adding `port` to `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` which Devise always tells us to do during installation but many of us ignore it.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

this is for `development.rb` anyway.

In production the value of the port will be a variable - `$PORT`, cos Heroku dynamically generates the port.